# Implementing Django ForeignKey-like subqueries without ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I have a non-ForeignKey ID from an external system that acts as my join key. I'd like to do Django ORM style queries using this ID.

My desired query is:

```
results = MyModel.objects.filter(level='M', children__name__contains='SOMETHING')
```

My model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    LEVELS = (
        ('I', 'Instance'),
        ('M', 'Master'),
        ('J', 'Joined')
    )

    level        = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LEVELS, default='I')
    parent       = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.SET_NULL )
    master_id    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
```

This works fine with `parent` as a field, but parent is redundant with the `master_id` field: `master_id` indicates which children belong to which master node. I'd like to get rid of `parent` (primarily because the dataset is fairly large and setting the parent IDs when importing data takes a long time).

The SQL equivalent of what I'm looking for is:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT( s_m.master_id )
FROM
    mytable s_m JOIN
    mytable s_i ON
        s_i.level = 'I' and s_m.level='M' AND s_i.master_id == s_m.master_id
WHERE
    s_i.name like '%SOMETHING%';
```

I believe there's a way to use Manager or QuerySet to enable clean querying of children (in this case, the children's names) within the Django ORM framework, but I can't figure out how. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this?

```
table1.objects.filter(master_id__in=table2.objects.filter(level='I').values_list(master_id,flat=True),level='M',name__contains='SOMETHING').values_list(master_id).distinct()
```